# ¿Cuándo quitaron los acentos de las palabras como "fué"?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, rae

He leído que hace años la RAE cambiaron las reglas para quitar las tildes de las palabras como *fué*, *dió*, etc. ¿Cuándo pasó eso? ¿Por qué hizo este cambio la RAE? ¿Cuáles fueron las palabras afectadas?

Comment: http://alicia-sigloxxi.blogspot.com.ar/2011/01/nueva-normativa-ortografica-de-la-rae.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

En la publicación *Nuevas normas de prosodia y ortografía: declaradas de aplicación preceptiva desde 1.º de enero de 1959*, la RAE decretó que las palabras monosilábicas no deben llevar tilde, salvo tilde diacrítica en algunas de ellas. Con esta regla cayeron las tildes de *fué*, *vió*, *dió*, etc.

Después, en la edición del 2010 de la *Ortografía de la lengua española*, decretó que para las reglas de acentuación, los diptongos se deben considerar únicamente de manera ortográfica, y aquí perdieron la tilde varias palabras más, como lo explica Fran [en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3500/13628). En su explicación solo faltaba la primera parte.

Comment: Curiso que sea de 1959, ya que estudié primaria y bachillerato entre 1971-1981 y se nos enseñó que monosílabos como **fué**, **vió**, **dió** van con tilde.

Answer (score 17):

Como bien indicó [@angus en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3506/1674), precisamente las palabras que se citan en la pregunta ya perdieron la tilde mucho antes de 2010: en las entonces [Nuevas normas de prosodia y ortografía](https://www.bcn.cl/obtienearchivo?id=documentos/10221.1/44349/1/225847.pdf) de 1959 de la Real Academia Española, donde se indica que:

> Los monosílabos verbales fue, fui, dio y vio, se escribirán sin tilde.

Pero se pregunta por «palabras como fué, dió,etc.», y allí es donde entra la duda, pues se puede entender que la pregunta se extiende más allá de esos cuatro tiempos verbales a otras muchas más palabras monosílabas que también han perdido el acento, y entonces **ya no está tan claro** cuando se produce el cambio. Es verdad que en la misma obra de 1959 se estableció que si una palabra forma un diptongo de vocal tónica abierta (a, e, o) con una vocal átona cerrada (i, u) átona, o viceversa, se acentuará la abierta cuando lo dispongan las normas generales de acentuación, de modo que...

> Así, guión, Sion, no se acentúan gráficamente, por ser monosílabas, ...

**Pero** mientras que quitar la tilde de los cuatro monosílabos verbales creo que se aceptó sin mayores problemas (o quizás no, no tengo recuerdos claros de los 60), buena parte de la población no consideró que estas otras palabras tengan diptongos, sino hiatos, es decir, que fonéticamente no les parecían monosílabas, y en consecuencia, se siguió usando (mucho) «guión» o «Sión». Y tanto es así, que esta segunda «norma» del 59 quedó como <s>papel mojado</s> recomendación incluso en la [Ortografía de la lengua española de 1999](http://lya.fciencias.unam.mx/gfgf/ga20111/material/Ortografia.pdf), donde **se admitía guión, Sión, fié, huí, etc.** (pág. 27) y esto **se mantuvo como opcional hasta 2010**, y ya veremos si acaba de calar como norma, o termina siendo nuevamente una recomendación. Solo (sólo) el tiempo lo dirá.

Por tanto, el «cuándo» sin duda empieza al menos en 1959, pero (y como @angus también señala) ni mucho menos termina ahí, y a esa parte me refería en mi respuesta original.

---

**Respuesta original**

> ¿Cuándo pasó eso?

El 17 de diciembre de 2010, en una sesión conjunta del pleno de la Real Academia Española (RAE) y de la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española (ASALE), se  presentó la  RAE la nueva edición de la Ortografía de la lengua española, que viene a sustituir a la anteriormente vigente, de 1999.

> ¿Cuáles fueron las palabras afectadas?

**Las palabras con diptongos o triptongos ortográficos**: guion, truhan, fie, liais, etc.

Con independencia de cuál sea su articulación real en palabras concretas, se consideran siempre diptongos a efectos ortográficos las combinaciones siguientes:

Vocal abierta (/a/, /e/, /o/) seguida o precedida de vocal cerrada átona (/i/, /u/): estabais, confiar, diario, afeitar, viento, pie, doy, guion, aunar, acuario, actuado, reunir, sueño, estadounidense, antiguo.

Dos vocales cerradas distintas (/i/, /u/): triunfo, incluido, diurno, huir, viuda, ruido.

Del mismo modo, se consideran siempre triptongos a efectos ortográficos las secuencias constituidas por una vocal abierta entre dos vocales cerradas átonas: confiáis, actuáis, puntuéis, guau.

Como consecuencia de la aplicación de estas convenciones, un grupo limitado de **palabras que tradicionalmente se habían escrito con tilde pasan a considerarse monosílabas a efectos de acentuación gráfica**, conforme a su pronunciación real en algunos hispanohablantes **y a escribirse, por ello, sin tilde**, ya que **los monosílabos no se acentúan gráficamente, salvo los que llevan tilde diacrítica**.

Las palabras afectadas por este cambio son formas verbales como crie, crio (pron. [krié], [krió]), criais, crieis y las de voseo crias, cria (pron. [kriás], [kriá]), de criar; fie, fio (pron. [fié], [fió]), fiais, fieis y las de voseo fias, fia (pron. [fiás], [fiá]), de fiar; flui, fluis (de fluir); frio (pron. [frió]), friais, de freír; frui, fruis (de fruir); guie, guio (pron. [gié], [gió]), guiais, guieis y las de voseo guias, guia (pron. [giás], [giá]), de guiar; hui, huis (de huir); lie, lio (pron. [lié], [lió]), liais, lieis y las de voseo lias, lia (pron. [liás], [liá]), de liar; pie, pio (pron. [pié], [pió]), piais, pieis y las de voseo pias, pia (pron. [piás], [piá]), de piar; rio (pron. [rió]), riais, de reír; sustantivos como guion, ion, muon, pion, prion, ruan y truhan; y ciertos nombres propios, como Ruan y Sion.

> ¿Por qué hizo este cambio la RAE?

Respuesta políticamente correcta:

Porque para poder aplicar con propiedad las reglas de acentuación gráfica del español es necesario determinar previamente la división de las palabras en sílabas.  Y para dividir silábicamente las palabras que contienen secuencias de vocales es preciso saber si dichas vocales se articulan dentro de la misma sílaba, como diptongos o triptongos (vais, o.pioi.de), o en sílabas distintas, como hiatos (lí.ne.a, ta.o.ís.ta). Pero al no existir uniformidad entre los hispanohablantes en la manera de articular muchas secuencias vocálicas (unos hablantes pronuncian las vocales contiguas dentro de la misma sílaba y otros en sílabas distintas) se estableció ya en 1999 una serie de convenciones para fijar qué combinaciones vocálicas deben considerarse siempre diptongos o triptongos y cuáles siempre hiatos a la hora de aplicar las reglas de acentuación gráfica.

**La ortografía de 1999, prescribía ya la escritura sin tilde** de estas palabras pero admitía que los hablantes que las pronunciasen como bisílabas pudiesen seguir acentuándolas. En  2010 se suprime dicha opción porque quiebra el principio de unidad ortográfica, de modo que las palabras que pasan a considerarse monosílabas por contener este tipo de diptongos o triptongos ortográficos deben escribirse ahora **obligatoriamente** sin tilde, con el fin de garantizar la unidad en la representación escrita.

Respuesta políticamente incorrecta:

Porque tenían ganas de marear la perdiz, o para adaptarse a los tiempos modernos, porque hay muchos que no saben (o no quieren) poner tildes. O quizás porque la RAE quería contentar a la ASALE sin pensar en las consecuencias. Quién sabe ...

(Si alguien deduce de la respuesta anterior que no me gusta mucho la citada norma, se equivoca: No me gusta nada).

Comment: Gracias Fran por hacer estas ediciones que ponen al día la respuesta. Viendo que no entrabas demasiado a menudo y que la respuesta es antigua, pensé que no estarías disponible. Ha sido fantástico ver que sí y que la marca de "aceptada" ahora sí hace justicia :) ¡Esperamos verte con frecuencia!

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias a tí. Cierto que no visito mucho Spanish Language, pero suelo entrar en otras  comunidades de StackExchange, así que no suelo tardar mucho en ver los comentarios.

Comment: Ouch ese _ti_ con tilde me dolió, y más en esta pregunta ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui Bueno, si "ti dolió", entonces no está mal del todo, para diferenciarlo del posesivo :D

Comment: @Fran lo que se ha visto es que la Real Academia Española como ama y señora incontrovertible del idioma español viene haciendo cambios más por razones políticas: una de ellas es por pertenecer a la Comunidad Europea y la otra razón es la informática: solo así se explica cambios como considerar que la CH y la LL no son consonantes en propiedad como se venía usando desde tiempos inmemoriables sino que son solo 2 letras continuas y eso fue para "facilitar" la ordenación de palabras en los sistemas de información, porque así se acostumbra en otros idiomas vivos que heredaron caracteres latinos.

Comment: @Fran, aun me confunde encontrar en los listados de países a **Chile** antes de **Colombia**. Estamos a un paso que nuestra querida  **Ñ** se llegue a considerar sencilamente como una **N** que solo se diferencia porque tiene el signo diacrítico virgulilla **~**.

Comment: @alvalongo  Todavía guardo un diccionario que tras  «Czarina»  viene «**CH.**  f. Letra consonante, cuarta de nuestro alfabeto. Su nombre es **che**.» pero ahora es   «ch. f. Dígrafo que representa el fonema consonántico africado palatal sordo, aunque en algunas zonas se realiza como fricativo». Mucho más claro así, donde va a parar, ja, ja,  ... pero hay que reconocer las peculiaridades del idioma español le complican mucho la vida a los algoritmos, y más cuando en lugar de UTF8 había ASCII y poco más.