# Accentuation of monosyllabic words

Tags: ortografía

So AFAIK monosyllabic words do not come with accentuation, except for they are used to distiguish them (que/qué). I came across some verses from the scriptures, that amazed me. In in the 1960 edition of the translation of Reina Valera e. g. Genesis 1:4 looks like so

> Y vio Dios que la luz era buena (Reina Valera 1960)

But in the 1909 edition, the same vers looks like so

> Y vió Dios que la luz era buena (Reina Valera 1909)

Is that a flaw in the edition I have or did anything change between 1909 and 1960?

Comment: These are called "tildes (or acentos) diacríticos". This can be either a [common] mistake in the book from 1909 or a case in which the acento diacrítico was added afterwords. However, I would go for the first reason, since "vio" does not have any other meaning.

Comment: [This response](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3497/cu%C3%A1ndo-quitaron-los-acentos-de-las-palabras-como-fu%C3%A9/3506#3506) answer your question. Another answers in same post are very informative. [This post](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/editions-of-spanish-orthographies/10329#10329) shows the evolution of spelling rules of the RAE.

Comment: @Rodrigo I think you shall post this is an answer (and maybe elaborate a bit more with information from both links)