# Water and gas went off (unavailable)

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I'm taking a shower and then suddenly the water stopped coming out from the shower.

What would a Spanish speaking person say in this situation? (right at that moment)

**Are these sentences correct?**

> No hay agua.
>
> Se ha ido el agua.

And after this disaster , I go to the kitchen to make lunch. The stove is not working.

---

**Can I say:** (right at that moment)

> No hay gas.
>
> Se ha ido el gas.

I would be grateful if you could answer my question.

---

**Thank you.**

Comment: All of your solutions are correct. «No hay» can be used for more unspecific cases (example: you don't know for how long the house hasn't had water). «Se ha ido» has a more immediate sense: there was water a moment ago, now there isn't. The only case I wouldn't use «irse» is for *bottled* gas, in which case I would use «agotarse» or «acabarse», but it's fine for *piped* gas or other immaterial services _perceived_ as a flow from an external source: cobertura (mobile), señal (TV, radio)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **In the case of water:**

> -*Se cortó el agua.*
>
> -*Me he quedado sin agua.*
>
> -*Se fue el agua*

---

- **in the case of gas:**

> -*Me he quedado sin gas.*
>
> -*La cocina se ha quedado sin gas.*
>
> -*La garrafa de gas esta vacía.*

Comment: Attention the the «eh» «ah»! Those are interjections. The correct verbs are «he», «ha». Also, «cortó» and «está» need their accent marks. cc/ @keramus

Comment: Yes sorry! is HE, no EH! siempre me confundo!

Comment: I agree 100% with @Lobo-Eze when he says "se fue el agua" but careful, it's completely wrong to use accent on "fue".  Here, two references: http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/alhabla/museo_horrores/museo_028.htm
http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3497/cu%C3%A1ndo-quitaron-los-acentos-de-las-palabras-como-fu%C3%A9
Now, in the case of gas, "No hay gas". It depends how is your service of gas. Some people in Latin America don't use gas from pipes, but in a sort of small containers. In that case people say "Se acabó el gas". In both disasters you can swear also. Interested? Let me know.

Comment: so if the example *-La garrafa de gas esta vacía.* hehehe

Comment: hehe, This is the first time that I heard about "garrafa de gas". In South America, some say "balón de gas" or "tanque de gas". But in that case anyway they say "Se acabó el gas, llama al proveedor para que nos traiga uno nuevo" (Call the company of gas to bring us a new one).

Comment: Es que soy de Argentina jaja :P